# Spell Strike + Touch Injection?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, touch-attacks

> [*Spell Strike (Su)*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/archetypes/paizo---arcanist-archetypes/blade-adept): The blade adept can deliver touch spells with her bonded weapon. This works as the [magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus) ability of the same name.

[Touch Injection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Touch-Attacks)

> **Range** personal
>   **Target** you
>
> [...]
>
> While the spell lasts, you can deliver the substance with a mere touch. To do so to an opponent, you must make a successful melee [touch attack]

[Touch Attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Touch-Attacks)

> Some attacks completely disregard armor, including shields and natural armor—the aggressor need only touch a foe for such an attack to take full effect. In these cases, the attacker makes a touch attack roll (either ranged or melee).

Can I deliver the effect from Touch Injection using a weapon (by using the Spell Strike ability)?

I presume no. I can't find a concrete definition of touch spell, but I presume it's supposed to be in [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Range):

> ## **Range**
>
> [...]
>
> ### Touch
>
> You must touch a creature or object to affect it. A touch spell that deals damage can score a critical hit just as a weapon can.

It is only implied that spells with a range of touch are touch spells, and it is only implied, if at all, that spells with a range of touch are the only things that can be considered touch spells.

Can Spell Strike deliver the Touch Injection spell's touch attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Touch Injection isn't a touch spell (its range is “personnal”) and the delivery is not a spell (just a touch attack), so you can't use Spell Strike.

> At 2nd level, whenever a magus casts **a spell with a range of “touch”** from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack. Instead of the free melee touch attack normally allowed to deliver the spell, a magus can make one free melee attack with his weapon (at his highest base attack bonus) as part of casting this spell.

(emphasize mine)

Flavor-wise, since

> You must hold an elixir, infused extract, poison, or potion in hand as you cast this spell. The held substance drains from its container **into a magical sac in your body**.

I'd say you can't use your sword.